# Existence of a meromorphic functions $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)|\geq |z|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|\geq |z|$ at each $z$, where $f$ is holomorphic. Then, which of the following is/are true.

1. The hypothesis are contradictory, so no such $f$ exists.
2. Such an $f$ is entire.
3. There is a unique $f$ satisfying the given conditions.
4. There is an $A\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|A|\geq 1$ such that $f(z)=Az$ for each $z\in \mathbb{C}$

I think $1$ and $3$ are false but not sure. And what about $2$ and $4$? I am unable to find suitable examples. Please help me here.

Comment: To deal with 1. and 3., you can take a look at 4. If you find that the functions specified in 4. satisfy the hypotheses, you know there is more than one such function, showing 1. and 3. are false. For 2. and 4., consider the quotient $z/f(z)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit sir? I am still unable to see it clearly. @DanielFischer

Comment: Which part have you problems with?

Comment: Considering the quotient $z/f(z)$ how can i conclude that $f$ is entire? @DanielFischer

Comment: What can you say about the function $g \colon z \mapsto \frac{z}{f(z)}$?

Comment: Holomorphic I guess. @DanielFischer

Comment: On which set? Anything else?

Comment: Ummm not sure of anything else. The truth is my knowledge is very poor. As $f(z)$ is meromorphic so except the poles of $f(z)$ the function $g$ is holomorphic? Is that right?

Comment: The zeros of $f$ are also potential problems. But there's something you can say about $g$ regardless of any regularity properties of $f$, just from the inequality.

Comment: $|g(z)|<1$ right?

Comment: $\leqslant$, not necessarily $<$. Okay. What does that tell you about the singularities of $g$?

Comment: Singularities are inside the unit disk.

Comment: No, $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ is a constraint on the range of $g$, the singularities are in the domain. But the constraint on the range tells you the type of the singularities.

Comment: sorry I couldn't see it. I mean about the singularities in the range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be part of the problem statement that $f$ is meromorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$, we could not say much about $f$ if we only assume it is meromorphic on $\{z : \lvert z-5\rvert < 4\}$ for example.

Let's look at the slightly more general situation that we are given two functions $g,h$ that are meromorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Define $P(g)$ as the set of poles of $g$ and $P(h)$ analogously. Assume further that we have an inequality

$$\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert h(z)\rvert \tag{1}$$

for all $z$ such that neither $g$ nor $h$ has a pole at $z$.

If we know that $h \not\equiv 0$ - which is for example implied by $g\not\equiv 0$ - then we can look at the quotient

$$q(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)},$$

which we know is defined and holomorphic at least on $\mathbb{C}\setminus E$, where $E = P(g) \cup P(h) \cup h^{-1}(0)$. Since $h$ is not identically zero, $h^{-1}(0)$ is a closed and discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$. As a union of finitely many closed and discrete sets, $E$ is a closed and discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$, so $q$ is holomorphic except for isolated singularities on all of $\mathbb{C}$. From $(1)$, we immediately obtain $\lvert q(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus E$, so by Riemann's removable singularity theorem, all the isolated singularities of $q$ are removable, and $q$ has an extension to an entire function (which we again denote by $q$). The inequality $\lvert q(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ extends from $\mathbb{C}\setminus E$ to $\mathbb{C}$ by continuity, and hence Liouville's theorem tells us that $q$ is constant, $q(z) \equiv c$, where $\lvert c\rvert \leqslant 1$.

Thus $(1)$ implies that $g \equiv c\cdot h$ for some $c$ with $\lvert c\rvert \leqslant 1$. The argument above requires $h \not \equiv 0$, but the case $h \equiv 0$ immediately implies $g \equiv 0$, i.e. $g \equiv 1\cdot h$ (or $g \equiv 0\cdot h$, in this case $c$ isn't unique).

Applying this to the given situation with $g(z) = z$ should make it clear which of the points 1.-4. are true and which are false.

Comment: Don't we need additional assumption to show $g=ch$ for all $x$? For example $|z^2/z|\geq |z|$ but they are not equal everywhere. Does the equality only hold on $E^c$ (using your notation)? What if we make an additional assumption that $h,g$ are continuous, I think then the equality holds for all $x$. I am sorry if this is a lot of questions, I could just make post a new question regarding this.

Comment: @Sorfosh One considers removable singularities removed (except when one is discussing removable singularities). And if we consider meromorphic functions as maps to the Riemann sphere, then the equality $g(z) = c\cdot h(z)$ holds for all $z$ as long as $c \neq 0$ (with $c = 0$ we get a $0 \cdot \infty$ problem at the poles). If we consider them as functions to $\mathbb{C}$ defined on the complement of some closed discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then we have the equality on the common domain. But that is not the best viewpoint.

Comment: It's better to consider them as elements of the field of entire meromorphic functions. In this view, we have the plain $g = ch$, just like as rational functions we have $\frac{X^2-1}{X-1} = X + 1$.